# Flexible Core Data Implementation

Tags: ios, core-data, parse-platform, cloud

I have been working on an app that uses Parse as its backend and while this works well, I don't want the app to become too dependent on Parse to work. Having the apps own Core Data implementation is probably the best way to go but the implementation must be flexible so that it can support syncing etc. I have been looking into frameworks like Ensembles, MagicalRecord, iOSDataManager and a number of others. I even looked at FTASync but this has not been updated for years and does not have a good reputation. I felt to ask the community what others may recommend as a good design of a backend system to sync with Parse or other web service.  Particularly considering how important the backend is...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have used Ensembles, and I recommend it highly.  The open source version is probably fine for your use, with the version 2 version available if you find you need any of the benefits for the paid upgrade.

If you want to see how to build a backend agnostic interface, then I also highly recommend studying the ensembles framework, especially how the interface for the cloud file system interface.

I have implemented my own backend for a specific project, and the interface is quite clear, and extremely useful for teaching one how to design and build such an interface.

Comment: Deeply appreciated your advice here Jody. I will investigate this for myself and let you know how I go

Comment: @joshanangelofgrace you can also use Parse as backend for Ensembles. Some day you may easly migrate to other backend without changes in your model.

Comment: This is so true. Probably the best way of designing the app actually so that any backend changes don't impact the app itself